# What happens if I don't $redis = Redis.new in after_fork?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, unicorn

What's the negative impact of not putting `$redis = Redis.new` in Unicorn's after_fork, since redis-rb is thread safe?  Assuming I have more than one worker.

As opposed to just putting that line of code in the environment.rb or an intializer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`after_fork` has little to do with thread safety. It it used when a parent process forks a child process, not when spawning a thread.

**Why you should care**

If you never fork, you probably don't.

When you fork, the parent and child processes share file and socket descriptors (db connections, redis connections). If you don't re-open the connection to Redis in the child, data from the parent can be interleaved on the socket with data from the child.

Read [A Unix Shell in Ruby Pipes](http://jstorimer.com/2012/03/18/a-unix-shell-in-ruby-pipes.html) for a much more detailed description of what's going on.